# Building content shell as final and sharing

Tags: linux, google-chrome, build, chromium, ninja

everything good? I'm doing working on a personal project that aims to use the content_shell as a minimal browser, just for viewing sites on terminals and some other options I'm adding. For this I am using the content shell I built it in Ubuntu 16.04 with the following flags ng:

```
is_debug = false
is_java_debug = false
is_official_build = true
target_cpu = "x86"
symbol_level = 0
remove_webcore_debug_symbols = true
enable_nacl = false
is_component_build = true
```

He generated all of these files:

```
AHEM____.TTF
angledata
args.gn
brotli
build.ninja
build.ninja.d
character_data_generator
clang_newlib_x64
content_shell
content_shell.log
content_shell.pak
fonts.conf
font_service.service
GardinerModBug.ttf
GardinerModCat.ttf
gen
genmacro
genmodule
genperf
genstring
genversion
glibc_x64
icudtl.dat
irt_x64
libaccessibility.so
libaccessibility.so.TOC
libanimation.so
libanimation.so.TOC
libaura_extra.so
libaura_extra.so.TOC
libaura.so
libaura.so.TOC
libbase_i18n.so
libbase_i18n.so.TOC
libbase.so
libbase.so.TOC
libbindings.so
libbindings.so.TOC
libblink_android_mojo_bindings_shared.so
libblink_android_mojo_bindings_shared.so.TOC
libblink_common.so
libblink_common.so.TOC
libblink_controller.so
libblink_controller.so.TOC
libblink_core.so
libblink_core.so.TOC
libblink_deprecated_test_plugin.so
libblink_modules.so
libblink_modules.so.TOC
libblink_mojo_bindings_shared.so
libblink_mojo_bindings_shared.so.TOC
libblink_offscreen_canvas_mojo_bindings_shared.so
libblink_offscreen_canvas_mojo_bindings_shared.so.TOC
libblink_platform.so
libblink_platform.so.TOC
libblink_test_plugin.so
libbluetooth.so
libbluetooth.so.TOC
libboringssl.so
libboringssl.so.TOC
libcapture_base.so
libcapture_base.so.TOC
libcapture_lib.so
libcapture_lib.so.TOC
libcc_animation.so
libcc_animation.so.TOC
libcc_base.so
libcc_base.so.TOC
libcc_blink.so
libcc_blink.so.TOC
libcc_debug.so
libcc_debug.so.TOC
libcc_ipc.so
libcc_ipc.so.TOC
libcc_paint.so
libcc_paint.so.TOC
libcc.so
libcc.so.TOC
libcdm_manager.so
libcdm_manager.so.TOC
libchromium_sqlite3.so
libchromium_sqlite3.so.TOC
libcodec.so
libcodec.so.TOC
libcolor_space.so
libcolor_space.so.TOC
libcompositor.so
libcompositor.so.TOC
libcontent_common_mojo_bindings_shared.so
libcontent_common_mojo_bindings_shared.so.TOC
libcontent_public_common_mojo_bindings_shared.so
libcontent_public_common_mojo_bindings_shared.so.TOC
libcontent.so
libcontent.so.TOC
libcrcrypto.so
libcrcrypto.so.TOC
libc++.so
libc++.so.TOC
libdbus.so
libdbus.so.TOC
libdevice_base.so
libdevice_base.so.TOC
libdevice_event_log.so
libdevice_event_log.so.TOC
libdevice_gamepad.so
libdevice_gamepad.so.TOC
libdevices.so
libdevices.so.TOC
libdevice_vr_mojo_bindings_blink.so
libdevice_vr_mojo_bindings_blink.so.TOC
libdevice_vr_mojo_bindings_shared.so
libdevice_vr_mojo_bindings_shared.so.TOC
libdevice_vr_mojo_bindings.so
libdevice_vr_mojo_bindings.so.TOC
libdiscardable_memory_client.so
libdiscardable_memory_client.so.TOC
libdiscardable_memory_common.so
libdiscardable_memory_common.so.TOC
libdiscardable_memory_service.so
libdiscardable_memory_service.so.TOC
libdisplay.so
libdisplay.so.TOC
libdisplay_types.so
libdisplay_types.so.TOC
libdisplay_util.so
libdisplay_util.so.TOC
libEGL.so
libEGL.so.TOC
libembedder.so
libembedder.so.TOC
libevents_base.so
libevents_base.so.TOC
libevents_devices_x11.so
libevents_devices_x11.so.TOC
libevents_ozone_layout.so
libevents_ozone_layout.so.TOC
libevents.so
libevents.so.TOC
libevents_x.so
libevents_x.so.TOC
libffmpeg.so
libffmpeg.so.TOC
libfingerprint.so
libfingerprint.so.TOC
libfreetype.so.6
libfreetype.so.6.TOC
libgeolocation.so
libgeolocation.so.TOC
libgeometry_skia.so
libgeometry_skia.so.TOC
libgeometry.so
libgeometry.so.TOC
libgesture_detection.so
libgesture_detection.so.TOC
libgfx_ipc_color.so
libgfx_ipc_color.so.TOC
libgfx_ipc_geometry.so
libgfx_ipc_geometry.so.TOC
libgfx_ipc_skia.so
libgfx_ipc_skia.so.TOC
libgfx_ipc.so
libgfx_ipc.so.TOC
libgfx.so
libgfx.so.TOC
libgfx_switches.so
libgfx_switches.so.TOC
libgfx_x11.so
libgfx_x11.so.TOC
libgin.so
libgin.so.TOC
libgles2_c_lib.so
libgles2_c_lib.so.TOC
libgles2_implementation.so
libgles2_implementation.so.TOC
libgles2_utils.so
libgles2_utils.so.TOC
libGLESv2.so
libGLESv2.so.TOC
libgl_init.so
libgl_init.so.TOC
libgl_in_process_context.so
libgl_in_process_context.so.TOC
libgl_wrapper.so
libgl_wrapper.so.TOC
libgpu.so
libgpu.so.TOC
libhost.so
libhost.so.TOC
libicui18n.so
libicui18n.so.TOC
libicuuc.so
libicuuc.so.TOC
libinterfaces_shared.so
libinterfaces_shared.so.TOC
libipc_mojom_shared.so
libipc_mojom_shared.so.TOC
libipc_mojom.so
libipc_mojom.so.TOC
libipc.so
libipc.so.TOC
libjs.so
libjs.so.TOC
libkeycodes_x11.so
libkeycodes_x11.so.TOC
libkeyed_service_content.so
libkeyed_service_content.so.TOC
libkeyed_service_core.so
libkeyed_service_core.so.TOC
libmedia_blink.so
libmedia_blink.so.TOC
libmedia_gpu.so
libmedia_gpu.so.TOC
libmedia_mojo_services.so
libmedia_mojo_services.so.TOC
libmedia.so
libmedia.so.TOC
libmetrics_cpp.so
libmetrics_cpp.so.TOC
libmidi.so
libmidi.so.TOC
libmirclient.so.9
libmirclient.so.9.TOC
libmojo_common_lib.so
libmojo_common_lib.so.TOC
libmojo_ime_lib.so
libmojo_ime_lib.so.TOC
libmojo_public_system_cpp.so
libmojo_public_system_cpp.so.TOC
libmojo_public_system.so
libmojo_public_system.so.TOC
libmojo_system_impl.so
libmojo_system_impl.so.TOC
libnative_theme.so
libnative_theme.so.TOC
libnet.so
libnet.so.TOC
libnet_with_v8.so
libnet_with_v8.so.TOC
libosmesa.so
libplatform.so
libplatform.so.TOC
libppapi_host.so
libppapi_host.so.TOC
libppapi_proxy.so
libppapi_proxy.so.TOC
libppapi_shared.so
libppapi_shared.so.TOC
libprefs.so
libprefs.so.TOC
libprinting.so
libprinting.so.TOC
libprotobuf_lite.so
libprotobuf_lite.so.TOC
librange.so
librange.so.TOC
libresource_coordinator_cpp.so
libresource_coordinator_cpp.so.TOC
libresource_coordinator_public_interfaces_internal_shared.so
libresource_coordinator_public_interfaces_internal_shared.so.TOC
libsandbox_services.so
libsandbox_services.so.TOC
libseccomp_bpf.so
libseccomp_bpf.so.TOC
libsensors.so
libsensors.so.TOC
libservice_manager_cpp.so
libservice_manager_cpp.so.TOC
libservice_manager_cpp_types.so
libservice_manager_cpp_types.so.TOC
libservice_manager_mojom_blink.so
libservice_manager_mojom_blink.so.TOC
libservice_manager_mojom_constants_blink.so
libservice_manager_mojom_constants_blink.so.TOC
libservice_manager_mojom_constants_shared.so
libservice_manager_mojom_constants_shared.so.TOC
libservice_manager_mojom_constants.so
libservice_manager_mojom_constants.so.TOC
libservice_manager_mojom_shared.so
libservice_manager_mojom_shared.so.TOC
libservice_manager_mojom.so
libservice_manager_mojom.so.TOC
libservice.so
libservice.so.TOC
libshared_memory_support.so
libshared_memory_support.so.TOC
libshell_dialogs.so
libshell_dialogs.so.TOC
libskia.so
libskia.so.TOC
libsnapshot.so
libsnapshot.so.TOC
libsql.so
libsql.so.TOC
libstartup_tracing.so
libstartup_tracing.so.TOC
libstorage_browser.so
libstorage_browser.so.TOC
libstorage_common.so
libstorage_common.so.TOC
libstub_window.so
libstub_window.so.TOC
libsuid_sandbox_client.so
libsuid_sandbox_client.so.TOC
libsurface.so
libsurface.so.TOC
libtest_runner.so
libtest_runner.so.TOC
libtracing.so
libtracing.so.TOC
libui_base_ime.so
libui_base_ime.so.TOC
libui_base.so
libui_base.so.TOC
libui_base_x.so
libui_base_x.so.TOC
libui_data_pack.so
libui_data_pack.so.TOC
libui_touch_selection.so
libui_touch_selection.so.TOC
libui_views_mus_lib.so
libui_views_mus_lib.so.TOC
liburl_ipc.so
liburl_ipc.so.TOC
liburl.so
liburl.so.TOC
libuser_prefs.so
libuser_prefs.so.TOC
libv8_libbase.so
libv8_libbase.so.TOC
libv8_libplatform.so
libv8_libplatform.so.TOC
libv8.so
libv8.so.TOC
libviews.so
libviews.so.TOC
libviz_common.so
libviz_common.so.TOC
libviz_resource_format.so
libviz_resource_format.so.TOC
libVkLayer_core_validation.so
libVkLayer_core_validation.so.TOC
libVkLayer_object_tracker.so
libVkLayer_object_tracker.so.TOC
libVkLayer_parameter_validation.so
libVkLayer_parameter_validation.so.TOC
libVkLayer_swapchain.so
libVkLayer_swapchain.so.TOC
libVkLayer_threading.so
libVkLayer_threading.so.TOC
libVkLayer_unique_objects.so
libVkLayer_unique_objects.so.TOC
libweb_dialogs.so
libweb_dialogs.so.TOC
libwebview.so
libwebview.so.TOC
libwm_public.so
libwm_public.so.TOC
libwm.so
libwm.so.TOC
libwtf.so
libwtf.so.TOC
libx11_events_platform.so
libx11_events_platform.so.TOC
libx11_window.so
libx11_window.so.TOC
locales
mksnapshot
mus_app_resources_100.pak
mus_app_resources_200.pak
mus_app_resources_strings.pak
nacl_bootstrap_x64
natives_blob.bin
newlib_pnacl
newlib_pnacl_nonsfi
obj
protoc
proto_zero_plugin
pyproto
re2c
resources
shell_resources.pak
snapshot_blob.bin
swiftshader
test_ime_driver.service
toolchain.ninja
transport_security_state_generator
ui
ui_resources_100_percent.pak
ui.service
ui_test.pak
v8_build_config.json
v8_context_snapshot.bin
v8_context_snapshot_generator
views_mus_resources.pak
yasm
```

How do I make all these files with the same structure as the official Chromium? I removed the folders I do not need and the files add up to about 1.7 GB I want to share with others my project. I have already researched and am looking here in the group something about this but I have not yet found, which one or which command should I use to reduce the number of files, I know it is not identical however Electron uses the content_shell and the file structure is similar to of Chromium:

[Electron file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de0F2.png)

Do I have to build it again? If so, which flags should I use?

Thanks everyone for your attention :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `is_component_build = false` when invoking `gn` to generate `ninja` build files.

This is because when `is_component_build` is set to true, the build will generate a shared object for each component target to improve compile time (faster incremental builds), whereas when set to false it will produce static libs for each component and bundle them into a huge shared object to speed up the application at runtime (among other reasons).

Even if you need to build it on Linux, it might be helpful to have a look at [Checking out and Building Chromium for Windows # Faster builds](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#faster-builds) and [this answer](https://github.com/notwaldorf/ama/issues/34#issuecomment-185038702).